# How to save Stata dataset using looping variable

Tags: stata

I want to save different outputs as dta files which are named differently.

So I am doing the following.

```
forvalues i = 1(1)5 {

 import delimited input.txt 

 (some operations)

 save 'i'results.dta
}
```

But

```
save 'i'results.dta
```

doesn' seem to work in this context.

How can I save datasets each in different names in each different loop?

Answer (score 1):

The problem report "doesn't seem to work" is singularly vague, but an obvious problem with the code you give is that the quotation marks for accessing local macro contents are wrong.

```
save 'i'results.dta
```

should be

```
save `i'results.dta
```

The opening and closing marks are different. 
Otherwise macro references could not be nested and distinguishing between macro references and ordinary single quotation marks would be more problematic. See any introduction to local macros, e.g. [this manual chapter](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u18.pdf)